# What is the name of broadcast when a user enable data or disable data on Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My application want to know whether Data has been enabled or not. That is when a user enable the data (`Click the Settings->Data Manager->Data Delivery->Data Enabled`), what is the name of `broadcast` message the system send out ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have never seen a "Data Manager" screen in Settings, and I have looked at a *lot* of Android devices. Hence, this may be specific to your device.

Comment: @CommonsWare Probably meant Mobile networks->Data Enabled that's what I've figured. Just intuition. I might be wrong though. BTW. A BIG thanks for your books and tutorials can't thank you enough I guess for them.

Comment: @CommonsWare My phone is from Moto, so the settings name may a little different from yours.

Comment: @XinLiu trust me - HE had probably seen so many android devices that neither you nor me would see in our whole lives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
action:android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
```

http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/android/net/MobileDataStateTracker.html

`MobileDataStateTracker`(149): default Received state= DISCONNECTED, old= CONNECTED, reason= dataDisabled, apnTypeList= default,supl

http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.1_r1_src/android/net/NetworkStateTracker.html
`NetworkStateTracker`(149): setDetailed state, old =CONNECTED and new state=DISCONNECTED

http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/services/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java.shtml
`ConnectivityService`(149): ConnectivityChange for mobile: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED
ConnectivityService(149): `getMobileDataEnabled` returning true

---

hope it helps abit

Comment: @Benner you answer rocks, thanks a lot. BTW, how can you find the name of so many broadcast message ?